# How to get an element from a JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON with this two lines:

```
"colors": ["dark denim"]
"stocks": {"dark denim": {"128": 4, "134": 6, "140": 17, "146": 18, "152": 35, "158": 7, "164": 21}}
```

I have to check if the 'colors' value, in this case 'dark denim', has the same value as in the first field of 'stocks.

The 'colors' always has one value, and the first field in stock also.

This is the whole json line, if it helps:

```
{"meta": {"upload": "2019-06-20 10:15:14.580562"}, "url": {"it": ["https://www.zalando.it/name-it-nkfmello-jacket-small-dot-giacca-da-mezza-stagione-dark-denim-na823l0c7-k11.html"]}, "product_id": "https://www.zalando.it/name-it-nkfmello-jacket-small-dot-giacca-da-mezza-stagione-dark-denim-na823l0c7-k11.html", "source": "Zalando", "country": ["it"], "lang": "it", "ref": "NA823L0C7-K11", "sex": "girls", "main_title": {"it": "NKFMELLO JACKET SMALL DOT - Giacca da mezza stagione"}, "images": {"dark denim": ["https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/pdp-reco-2x/NA/82/3L/0C/7K/11/NA823L0C7-K11@9.jpg"]}, "price_hierarchy": {"type": "color", "dark denim": {"price": {"EUR": "18.89"}, "previous_price": {"EUR": "26.99"}}}, "details": {"colors": ["dark denim"], "material": "Composizione: 100% poliestere, Fodera: 100% cotone", "brand": "Name it", "sizes": {"dark denim": ["128", "134", "140", "146", "152", "158", "164"]}, "sizes_not_available": {"dark denim": []}, "all_sizes": {"dark denim": ["146", "158", "128", "140", "134", "152", "164"]}}, "description": {"it": "Colletto: Cappuccio, Chiusura: Cerniera, Tasche: Tasche con patta, Cappuccio: Cappuccio removibile, Fantasia: Pois Vestibilità: Normale, Lunghezza: Lunghezza normale, Lunghezza manica: Manica lunga, Lunghezza delle maniche: 49 cm nella taglia 128, Larghezza dello schienale: 32 cm nella taglia 128, Lunghezza totale: 55 cm nella taglia 128 Composizione: 100% poliestere"}, "category": {"it": ["abbigliamento"]}, "sub_category": {"it": ["giacche"]}, "stocks": {"dark denim": {"128": 4, "134": 6, "140": 17, "146": 18, "152": 35, "158": 7, "164": 21}}, "full_path": [["abbigliamento", "giacche"]]}
```

The code I have so far is:

```
import json

with open('zalando_it_zalando_it_20190620101450.jl') as json_file:
    for line in json_file:
        json_line = (json.loads(line))
        color_name = json_line['details']['colors']
        if json_line['stocks'][0] == color_name:
            print(color_name)
```

So as you can see, I tried access it using [0], but that doesn't work, because one its a list and the other one is a dictionary.

My question is: How can I check if the value of 'colors' is the same as the first field of 'stocks'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read json file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999460/how-to-read-json-file-in-python)

Comment: ```color_name``` is a list. you're comparing ```list``` with dictionary. Can you try ```color_name[0]``` in your check? btw, please edit the question with clear info.

Comment: No, it doesn't, because I know how to open the json, but I don't know how can I verify if the field after 'stocks' has the same name as the 'colours' value. So I can't use, for example: json_line['stocks'][color_name]. I've tried this also, and it doesn't work

Comment: True, @maverick_06, and I know this is not the right way to do it, but I don't have any clue of how I can access that element, and this is what I am asking

Comment: does your ```colors``` key always have one element in the value? like this: ```"colors": ["dark denim"]```. Can't it be ```"colors": ["dark denim", "light denim"]``` ?

Comment: Yes, @maverick_06, it's always just one value

Comment: @DarrylG, I can't do that, because it is a 'json lines' file, so it's a really big file, and I can't have it all load in memory. So I can load just a line (json) at a time

Comment: @CatargiuAndreea-Alexandra--does your code work with your example file?  I get an JSONDecodeError on lline  `json_line = (json.loads(line))` with the first line of the file.

Comment: @CatargiuAndreea-Alexandra--your file must be different from what you posted.  Each line in the file you posted is not a json string, so `json.loads(line)` won't parse.

Comment: I posted just a line, not the whole 'json lines' file. So I guess it doesn't work for you because you have just a json, not multiple json lines like I do. I mentioned that I posted the json line.

Comment: @DarrylG I figured it how I should do it. I posted the answer here

Comment: @CatargiuAndreea-Alexandra--glad you were able to solve it.  For the future, note stack overflow encourages posting a "Minimally Reproducible Example" so others can recreate your posted code.  So in this case the missing json lines made it dificult for others to contribute.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to tell you what I really needed. I'm new in Python, and json files that are this big.. I will try to learn how to add a question that is more on point for what I need.

Comment: @DarrylG, okay, thank you for your contribution, and for the advice! I'll keep that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description and information given, this should be your solution:

```
import json

with open("zalando_it_zalando_it_20190620101450.jl", "r") as jsondata:
    data = json.load(jsondata)

    colors = data["colors"]
    for colorKey in data["stocks"]:
        if colorKey in colors:
            print(colorKey)
```

We can load the json data directly from the file using `json.load`, which stores the json as a dictionary to the designated variable (In this code, `data`).

Then we get each color by getting the key to each stock using a for loop to iterate through all the keys in the dictionary provided by the `data["stocks"]`. Lastly, we check if the color from the currently checked stock exists in the list of valid colors in `data["colors"]`. If it is, we print the color.

Comment: This was suggested but his issue is the actual file is too large to be loaded in memory i.e.  insufficient memory for `data = json.load(jsondata)`

Answer (score 0):

So I had to access the key (color name) of the 'stocks' like:

```
color_name = json_line["details"]["colors"]
    colors = json_line["stocks"]
    for i in colors.keys():
        if i in color_name:
```